# Unable to create client secret from Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-b2b

My requirement is to create an Azure Active Directory Application and a client secret for that application via Powershell. I know how to do it via Azure Portal.
To create an Azure Active Directory Application I found this command:

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName DemoApp
```

This successfully created an Application. But my problem is with client secret.
Is there is any command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can create client secret by using the below PowerShell cmdlet:**

```
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -CustomKeyIdentifier SecretName -ObjectId Your_Object_Id -EndDate ((Get-Date).AddMonths(6))
```

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and was able to create **`client secret`** successfully for the Azure AD application like below:

[image]

**To confirm the above, check the portal like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Certificates & secrets*

[image]

**Reference:**

[New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the instant response! It Worked!!!